# equivalent of vector<T> in Java

Tags: java, c++, vector

I'm using Java programming language.

C++ has `vector<T>` and I need the equivalent vector in Java.

I want to convert this code to Java.

```
Vector<T> a[Maxn]; // Example: string, int, myclass, myvar, ...
int n;
cin >> n;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    T x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    x--, y--;
    v[x].push_back(y);
}
```

Comment: `List<T>` backed by `ArrayList<T>`. Note that Java doesn't handle real generics, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `List<T>`, Java has many better ways, take it easy!

you could [Search](https://www.google.com/#q=Arraylist) it...

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

> Resizable-array implementation of the List interface. Implements all
>   optional list operations, and permits all elements, including null. In
>   addition to implementing the List interface, this class provides
>   methods to manipulate the size of the array that is used internally to
>   store the list.

Something like this:

```
ArrayList ar = new ArrayList<String>();
ar.add("abc");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [java.util.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html). There are many concrete implementations of list including [java.util.ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Here is an example using `ArrayList` 
Note Java Collections e.g. `List<T>` make use of generics. Below I am using a list of `String`

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
list.add("some string");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this is the class you are looking for:

[java.util.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Comment: This is an interface, not a class which can actually be instantiated.

Comment: List is an interface. ArrayList is a commonly used implementation (class).

Comment: The linked Java doc lists a selection of implementing classes.  Believe it or not, `ArrayList` is not the only class that implements `List`.  The distinction between interfaces and classes here is moot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something analogous to C++'s `std::vector`, I would start by looking at the various classes that implement the `List` interface (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Probably the most commonly-used `List` is [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), which has all the normal operations you would expect - `add`, `get`, `size`, `iterator`, etc.

Alternatively there is [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), which is useful in its own way, depending on what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score -2):

EDIT:  I do not advocate using `java.util.Vector<E>`, but since you are coming from a C background, it might give you a warm fuzzy to use the same name. However, you should note (from [the Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html))

> Unlike the new collection implementations, Vector is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector.

So it's best to use some other implementation of `java.util.List<E>` -- most common to use `java.util.ArrayList<E>`

Comment: So why use Vector over the *newer* ArrayList? (C++'s vector has no such synchronization guarantees.)

Comment: Only use Vector if you *need* sychronization (thread safety).  If the container won't be accessed from multiple threads, there's no need to incur the overhead.

Comment: Hmmm.  Now down voting correct answers.  Sweet.

Comment: Read this: [Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1386275/1065197)

Comment: I'm not advocating the use of Vector.  Just that it IS available.  editing my answer...

Comment: Still you're promoting to use something that you should not.

Comment: I disagree that I'm "promoting it."  I actually don't recommend it.

Comment: Since 1) it's obsolete/deprecated, and 2) nothing in the OP's post indicated that s/he expected any sort of synchronization, I'd argue that it isn't worth mentioning.

Comment: @CmdrMoozy `Stack` extends from `Vector`. You should update your answer as well...

Comment: Obsolete?  Sure.  Deprecated?  Not seeing that in the API.  And I think it is worth mentioning, at least in a dark manner, since there's so much code out there using it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You're right - I didn't look closely enough at the docs before adding it to my answer.

Comment: It is worth to mentioning as *you just at least know of the existence of this class, but **do not** use it*. Before your edits, you were promoting the usage of this class, that's why I downvoted it.

Comment: @CmdrMoozy anyway, for both of you, there's no meaning to answer a duplicated question to begin with...